# Laravel get order position

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a table USERS and Table POSTS in my database.

Relation (class User):

```
public function Posts() {
    return $this->hasMany('Post', 'uid', 'id');
}
```

My question is: How can I query users and order them by their number of posts and how can I display their Rank position?

For example

```
RANK_POS    UID    USER    NUMBER_OF_POSTS
1           5      USER5   23
2           3      USER3   20
3           6      USER6   2
4           1      USER7   2
5           2      USER2   0
```

So, I need to count posts for all users and order them by the number of posts and also generate rank position.

I tried this

```
public static function Rank() {
    return DB::table('users')
        ->leftJoin('posts', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user')            
        ->select(DB::raw('users.id, count(posts.id) as POSTS, users.name, users.surname, users.nickname'))
        ->groupBy('user.id');
}
```

This gives me more or less good result but still I can't get Rank position and can't order by POSTS.

If I try to add order

```
public static function Rank() {
    return DB::table('users')
        ->leftJoin('link_analytics', 'users.id', '=', 'link_analytics.user')            
        ->select(DB::raw('users.id, count(link_analytics.id) as CONVERSIONS, users.name, users.surname, users.nickname'))
        ->groupBy('link_analytics.user')
        ->orderBy('POSTS');
}
```

It gives me an error UNKNOWN COLUMN 'POSTS'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function Posts() {
    return DB::select("SELECT @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS RANK_POS, a.id as uid, a.user, 
                        IFNULL(b.NUMBER_OF_POSTS, 0) AS NUMBER_OF_POSTS
                        FROM users AS a
                        LEFT JOIN (
                           SELECT uid, count(*) as NUMBER_OF_POSTS
                           FROM posts
                           GROUP BY uid
                        ) AS b ON a.id = b.uid  
                        JOIN  (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
                        order by NUMBER_OF_POSTS desc ");
        }
```

Comment: And how can I order that by number of posts and display ranking position?

Comment: NUMBER_OF_POSTS is a order by and display ranking position.